# How to learn the necessary anthropology to create social software?

Tags: social-networking

Joel Spolsky repeats over and over that today, knowing a bit of anthropology can be very useful for a programer because much of what's being created is social software.

How can someone that already knows the computer science learn the anthropology needed to know how human beings works? Any books? Any recorded lectures?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that knowing a bit about how we think is more important now for a developer then ever. The book [Consciousness Explained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316180661) by Dan Dennett was a real eye opener for me in understanding that we don't think the way we think we think.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Clay Shirky's site](http://www.shirky.com/) is a good place to start. It's social anthropology set in a context of the internet, so it's more accessible (to programmers) than purely academic anthropology.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book I've heard is good, but didn't have a chance to dig through it yet: [Programming collective intelligence](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321/). It gives you some algorithms to quantify human behavior in social software. Sounds interesting.

Mathew Podwysocki wrote a post some time ago about [implementing these ideas in Haskell](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/04/17/haskell-and-collective-intelligence.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that approaching contemporary anthropology is a whole is
the absolute best way to develop the knowledge that you
seek. Anthropologists study a bunch of different things, and while
knowing this stuff will help you be able to develop better designs and
products, this is a case where being a generalist is probably not an
effective use of time.

Anthropologists study *culture*, the superstructural stuff that
happens when you put a bunch of people in close proximity and let the
situation stew for a while. Apologies for the rough
definition. Knowing about culture, how cultures and societies
function, what causes them to break, what causes them to flourish is
fascinating and useful. Reading the "anthropological cannon" will help
you begin to understand this, but again long road, and I think the
questions you need answered are more easily addressed with some
specific projects.

First I'd like to just characterize Anthropology for a moment:
Although Anthropology isn't an *experimental* field, it's incredibly
*empirical*. Anthropologists collect a lot of data, and attempt to
describe what they see as totally as possible. This methodology, and
approach is--I think--extremely useful to software developers. It's
very easy to say "people want this," or "users feel this way," about a
feature or aspect of your software based on your experiences. It's
terribly difficult to figure out how users actually feel and interact
with your software in a precise way. If you had to take one
Anthropology class as a software developer, I'd recommend something
with a methodological emphasis.

In terms of specific resources, the following directions spring to mind

Dona Harroway's "[The Cyborg Manifesto](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/HPS/Haraway/CyborgManifesto.html)," springs instantly to mind as
the foundational work in a field of study that explores the
interaction between people, and machines as a social phenomena. It's
short. Good read. [Amber Case](http://www.oakhazelnut.com/), a young "cyborg anthropologist" does
work in Harroway's tradition, and I'd follow up on both of these
folks.

Secondly, I'd explore studies of cities and small communities. Except
in some very extreme cases (i.e. Twitter, Facebook, etc.), whole
cultures aren't using your software. Groups are. Learn about them. I
think urban studies and work that gets called "urban sociology" might
begin to provide you the kinds of answer that you'd be interested
in. I think that would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The only rule to know about social software is that "people will do anything to make money or get laid" :)

But on a serious note, I don't think anthropology is what matters, but rather an understanding of the motivation that people have to contribute to social software or to expose themselves on social software. There have been quite a few recent books that explain a lot of these concepts in good terms. A good start could be "Here comes everybody" by Clay Shriky.

Comment: LOL. I just read, to confirm this, a comment on SO, right here.. Along that line that making iTwat apps will get you into a BMW convertible or some such.. Incredible variety, one aspect to never underestimate designs of 'yet another freeform bulletin board'.

Answer (score 0):

[The Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465067107)

[The Humane Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379376)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers here are pointing towards texts on how consciousness works or how people interact with devices. This is a great start, since it shows where you would want to go. Beyond that, you could consider understanding fundamental social and experiential aspects of how humans work. This way, you can develop software with an understanding of how humans could experience your software, as well as how it could be part of a social world.

To this I recommend The Ethical Primate from Mary Midgley. The text is about philosophy, ethics, freedom, and evolution, but it is firmly grounded in empirical knowledge. It will also give you tools to be able to critically examine the language and knowledge that—in my experience as a computer science major—STEM usually uses when discussing people. If you want to read a shorter text regarding this last point on the dangers of STEM language when describing humans, you could read Mary Midgley's Biotechnology and Monstruosity.

A text that deals less with the ethical and social implications of theorizing about humans is The Tangled Wing.

There are many ethnographies that describe how people interact with technologies such as social media. These are more specific to the kind of technology that you're working on.